# Why the implementation classes in Android/iOS folders are not recognized by the shared library in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin.forms.

I need to measure the size of a label based on its content. Because this is platform specific. I created an interface in the shared library, and two implementations in the iOS and Android folders.
Here is the declaration of the interface:

```
public interface ITextMeasurement
{
    double MeasureTextHeight(string text, double width, double fontSize, string fontName = null);
        
}
```

In the specific platform, for example iOS, I have the implementation class like this:

```
class TextMeasurementImpl : ITextMeasurement
    {
        public double MeasureTextHeight(string text, double width, double fontSize, string fontName = null)
        {
            var nsText = new NSString(text);
            var boundSize = new SizeF((float)width, float.MaxValue);
            ....
            var sizeF = nsText.GetBoundingRect(boundSize, options, attributes, null).Size;
            return (double)sizeF.Height;
        }
    }
```

However, when I tried to instantiate the class in the shared library, the class name was flagged as "Type or namespace name 'TextMeasurementImpl' could not be found". Since both Android and iOS implementations had the same signature, I didn't check the platform. Even if I do the checking, I still got the error.

```
 TextMeasurementImpl labelMeas = new TextMeasurementImpl().MeasureTextHeight();
```

I was following this link to create the platform specific implementation:
https://gist.github.com/alexrainman/82b00160ab32bef9e69dee6d460f44fa

Comment: you have to use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using it the wrong way, you need to do like this:

in your forms project:

```
double  textHeight = DependencyService.Get<ITextMeasurement>().MeasureTextHeight("your text", width,fontsize,fontname);
```

Comment: I found that the measured value was incorrect. So I put a breakpoint in the iOS implementation ( I was running iOS simulator), but the breakpoint was never hit.

Comment: I found that even though I was debugging, I set the debugging mode to Release. Once I changed it back to Debug, I could stepped into the implementation code.